# WCF Data Service OData; Way to specify JSON "verbose" with $format?

Tags: wcf-data-services, odata

WCF Data Services changes its response JSON format based on the `Accept:` header, so these 2 headers provide different results:

```
Accept: application/json
Accept: application/json; odata=verbose
```

However, the OData spec provides the `$format=` query parameter that should do the same thing. WCF seems to respect `$format=json` parameter, but treats it like the `application/json` accept header. But I want the verbose JSON...

So my question then is; what are the possible values for `$format=`? Is there a way to specify verbose JSON using it?

(I already know I can change my code to use the accept header, but existing code is using $format, so I prefer to change that instead.)

I'm using the pre-release WCF Data Services, v5.1.0-rc2

---

**Edit:**

My request looks like this:

URL:

```
http://localhost:52116/Services/MusicStore.svc/Albums?$format=json&%24inlinecount=allpages&%24filter=substringof('the'%2Ctolower(Title))
```

Request Headers:

```
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
DataServiceVersion: 3.0
Host: localhost:52116
MaxDataServiceVersion: 3.0
MinDataServiceVersion: 3.0
Proxy-Connection: keep-alive
Referer: http://localhost:52116/
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/22.0.1229.94 Safari/537.4
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
```

This returns valid JSON (non-verbose).

However if I try `$format=jsonverbose` then I get an HTTP 500 from WCF, with this in the trace logs:

```
<Exception>
<ExceptionType>System.ServiceModel.CommunicationObjectAbortedException, System.ServiceModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</ExceptionType>
<Message>The communication object, System.ServiceModel.Channels.TransportReplyChannelAcceptor+TransportReplyChannel, cannot be used for communication because it has been Aborted.</Message>
<StackTrace>
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.ThrowIfAborted()
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.InputQueueChannel`1.EndDequeue(IAsyncResult result, TDisposable&amp; item)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ReplyChannel.EndTryReceiveRequest(IAsyncResult result, RequestContext&amp; context)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ReplyChannelBinder.EndTryReceive(IAsyncResult result, RequestContext&amp; requestContext)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ErrorHandlingReceiver.EndTryReceive(IAsyncResult result, RequestContext&amp; requestContext)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ChannelHandler.EndTryReceive(IAsyncResult result, RequestContext&amp; requestContext)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ChannelHandler.AsyncMessagePump(IAsyncResult result)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ChannelHandler.OnAsyncReceiveComplete(IAsyncResult result)
at System.Runtime.Fx.AsyncThunk.UnhandledExceptionFrame(IAsyncResult result)
at System.ServiceModel.Diagnostics.TraceUtility.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClass4.&lt;CallbackGenerator&gt;b__2(AsyncCallback callback, IAsyncResult result)
at System.Runtime.AsyncResult.Complete(Boolean completedSynchronously)
at System.Runtime.AsyncResult.Complete(Boolean completedSynchronously, Exception exception)
at System.Runtime.InputQueue`1.AsyncQueueReader.Set(Item item)
at System.Runtime.InputQueue`1.Shutdown(Func`1 pendingExceptionGenerator)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.InputQueueChannel`1.OnClosing()
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Abort()
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ReplyChannelBinder.Abort()
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.OnAbort()
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Abort()
at System.Data.Services.DelegateBodyWriter.OnWriteBodyContents(XmlDictionaryWriter writer)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.BodyWriter.WriteBodyContents(XmlDictionaryWriter writer)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.BodyWriterMessage.OnWriteBodyContents(XmlDictionaryWriter writer)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message.OnWriteMessage(XmlDictionaryWriter writer)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message.WriteMessage(XmlDictionaryWriter writer)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message.WriteMessage(XmlWriter writer)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ByteStreamMessageEncoder.WriteMessage(Message message, Int32 maxMessageSize, BufferManager bufferManager, Int32 messageOffset)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.WebMessageEncoderFactory.WebMessageEncoder.WriteMessage(Message message, Int32 maxMessageSize, BufferManager bufferManager, Int32 messageOffset)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.MessageEncoder.WriteMessage(Message message, Int32 maxMessageSize, BufferManager bufferManager)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpOutput.SerializeBufferedMessage(Message message)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpOutput.Send(TimeSpan timeout)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpPipeline.EmptyHttpPipeline.SendReplyCore(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpPipeline.EmptyHttpPipeline.SendReply(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpRequestContext.OnReply(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
at System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpContext.OnReply(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestContextBase.Reply(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.Reply(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage9(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage8(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage6(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage41(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage4(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage31(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage3(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage2(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage11(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage1(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean isOperationContextSet)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.Dispatch(MessageRpc&amp; rpc, Boolean isOperationContextSet)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ChannelHandler.DispatchAndReleasePump(RequestContext request, Boolean cleanThread, OperationContext currentOperationContext)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ChannelHandler.HandleRequest(RequestContext request, OperationContext currentOperationContext)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ChannelHandler.AsyncMessagePump(IAsyncResult result)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ChannelHandler.OnAsyncReceiveComplete(IAsyncResult result)
at System.Runtime.Fx.AsyncThunk.UnhandledExceptionFrame(IAsyncResult result)
at System.ServiceModel.Diagnostics.TraceUtility.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClass4.&lt;CallbackGenerator&gt;b__2(AsyncCallback callback, IAsyncResult result)
at System.Runtime.AsyncResult.Complete(Boolean completedSynchronously)
at System.Runtime.AsyncResult.Complete(Boolean completedSynchronously, Exception exception)
at System.Runtime.InputQueue`1.AsyncQueueReader.Set(Item item)
at System.Runtime.InputQueue`1.EnqueueAndDispatch(Item item, Boolean canDispatchOnThisThread)
at System.Runtime.InputQueue`1.EnqueueAndDispatch(T item, Action dequeuedCallback, Boolean canDispatchOnThisThread)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.InputQueueChannel`1.EnqueueAndDispatch(TDisposable item, Action dequeuedCallback, Boolean canDispatchOnThisThread)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SingletonChannelAcceptor`3.Enqueue(QueueItemType item, Action dequeuedCallback, Boolean canDispatchOnThisThread)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpPipeline.EnqueueMessageAsyncResult.CompleteParseAndEnqueue(IAsyncResult result)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpPipeline.EnqueueMessageAsyncResult.HandleParseIncomingMessage(IAsyncResult result)
at System.Runtime.AsyncResult.SyncContinue(IAsyncResult result)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpPipeline.EnqueueMessageAsyncResult..ctor(ReplyChannelAcceptor acceptor, Action dequeuedCallback, HttpPipeline pipeline, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpPipeline.EmptyHttpPipeline.BeginProcessInboundRequest(ReplyChannelAcceptor replyChannelAcceptor, Action dequeuedCallback, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpRequestContext.BeginProcessInboundRequest(ReplyChannelAcceptor replyChannelAcceptor, Action acceptorCallback, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelListener`1.HttpContextReceivedAsyncResult`1.ProcessHttpContextAsync()
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelListener`1.HttpContextReceivedAsyncResult`1..ctor(HttpRequestContext requestContext, Action acceptorCallback, HttpChannelListener`1 listener, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelListener`1.BeginHttpContextReceived(HttpRequestContext context, Action acceptorCallback, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
at System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpTransportManager.HttpContextReceived(HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult result)
at System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.HandleRequest()
at System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.BeginRequest()
at System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.OnBeginRequest(Object state)
at System.ServiceModel.AspNetPartialTrustHelpers.PartialTrustInvoke(ContextCallback callback, Object state)
at System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.OnBeginRequestWithFlow(Object state)
at System.Runtime.IOThreadScheduler.ScheduledOverlapped.IOCallback(UInt32 errorCode, UInt32 numBytes, NativeOverlapped* nativeOverlapped)
at System.Runtime.Fx.IOCompletionThunk.UnhandledExceptionFrame(UInt32 error, UInt32 bytesRead, NativeOverlapped* nativeOverlapped)
at System.Threading._IOCompletionCallback.PerformIOCompletionCallback(UInt32 errorCode, UInt32 numBytes, NativeOverlapped* pOVERLAP)
</StackTrace>
<ExceptionString>System.ServiceModel.CommunicationObjectAbortedException: The communication object, System.ServiceModel.Channels.TransportReplyChannelAcceptor+TransportReplyChannel, cannot be used for communication because it has been Aborted.</ExceptionString>
```

---

**Edit 2:**

OK, So while `$format=jsonverbose` seems to HTTP500, this URL does give me what I want:

```
http://localhost:52116/Services/MusicStore.svc/Albums?$format=application%2fjson%3bodata%3dverbose&%24inlinecount=allpages&%24filter=substringof('the'%2Ctolower(Title))
```

So basically it is `$format=application/json;odata=verbose` URL escaped.

Awesome!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The $format header in 5.1.0 will accept the following values:

- json
- verbosejson
- atom

Any other value will try to be interpreted as a literal value for the Accept header, e.g. $format=application/json;odata=verbose is a synonym for $format=jsonverbose.

I commonly use the following:

- $format=json
- $format=verbosejson
- $format=application/json;odata=fullmetadata

Comment: are those the only two values possible for the `odata`param?

Comment: Just tweeted you too Mark, but if I flip to "jsonverbose", I get an HTTP 500 w/ this in trace log: `System.ServiceModel.CommunicationObjectAbortedException, System.ServiceModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089` Message: `The communication object, System.ServiceModel.Channels.TransportReplyChannelAcceptor+TransportReplyChannel, cannot be used for communication because it has been Aborted.` I'll add more detail to my original post above...

Comment: Your last line there tipped me off to trying `$format=application/json;odata=verbose` in the query string, which does work. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Sorry, it's verbosejson, not jsonverbose. Ugh. Answer updated above.